# How can I get my loop to not reprint its old value?

Tags: java

Right now, when I get "Would you like to continue", if I press y (or Y), the program will just reprint the previous typed in value with the same question afterwards. How can I solve this? Thank you.

```
class PrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = 0;
        char choice = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter integer ");
            value = console.nextInt();

            for (int i = 2; i < value; i++) {
                if (value % i == 0) { // checks if value is evenly divisible by any number
                    System.out.println(value + " is not a prime number ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(value + " is a prime number ");
                }
                System.out.print("Would you like to continue y/n ");
                choice = console.next().charAt(0);
            }
        } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
    }
}
```

Comment: Always indent your code properly. You should now see some larger errors.

Comment: I had to compile the code before I figured out that one.

Comment: There is also a problem with the prime number check.

Comment: Sorry flakes, Im new to java and Im really bad at structuring my code. ill try to practice on that!

Comment: I think the math of the prime factor is fine, its just that it keeps duplicating since its part of the for loop somehow. so if i enter 5, the message of "5 is a prime number" is gonna appear 3 times. i dont know how to fix it

Comment: With your algorithm, the only way to show a number is prime is to go through the loop and not have a match. This isn't a very efficient version, but it's easy to understand.

Comment: yeah I know, im just trying to get used to the loop system by, possibly, overdoing certain steps, but its for practice i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to address the following things in your code:

1. You need to check only up to the square root of the number. Check [Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).
2. You should break the loop as soon as it is found that the number is not prime.
3. You need to use `console.nextLine()` instead of `console.nextInt()` or `console.next()`. Check [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) for more details.

**Code incorporating the comments mentioned above:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = 0, i;
        char choice = 0;
        boolean valid;
        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Enter integer: ");
            try {
                value = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
                for (i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(value); i++) {
                    if (value % i == 0) { // checks if value is evenly divisible by any number
                        System.out.println(value + " is not a prime number ");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (i > Math.sqrt(value)) {
                    System.out.println(value + " is a prime number ");
                }
                System.out.print("Would you like to continue y/n: ");
                choice = console.nextLine().charAt(0);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("This is an invalid input. Try again.");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid || choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter integer: a
This is an invalid input. Try again.
Enter integer: 2
2 is a prime number 
Would you like to continue y/n: y
Enter integer: 91
91 is not a prime number 
Would you like to continue y/n: n
```

Comment: Awesome i like this version, thanks! (I have to learn about "try-catch"...)

Answer (score 1):

```
class PrimeNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value = 0;
    char choice = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter integer ");
        value = console.nextInt();

        for (int i = 2; i < value; i++) {
            if (value % i == 0) { // checks if value is evenly divisible by any number
                System.out.println(value + " is not a prime number ");
                break;
            } if(i==value-1){
                System.out.println(value + " is a prime number ");
            }
             }
            System.out.print("Would you like to continue y/n ");
            choice = console.next().charAt(0);

    } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
}
}
```

Comment: a minus one? why minus 1 :O i dont understand.

Comment: bcoz ,  last iteration for I will be value -1 , and since all the values from 2 to the number is checked , thus the number is prime , run this code you will understand better it's logic ,

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the user to answer `y` or `n` while still inside the `for` loop.
Try debugging your app to see how it behaves while you're executing it.

Comment: right right, i i tried to change the location of one of my curly braces, tried every spot, nothing helps. maybe i have a wrong loop type somewhere

Comment: It works fine once it's in the right place. Think of the flow of control of the program. The for loop calculates the prime, and the do/while loop is to redo the entire "get an integer/check for prime" part of the code. So the while loop is outside of the for loop. You might look at it from the outside-in. That is, the do/while loop contains the user-interface (asking the user to input a number, and if they want to continue. The for loop is inside of this, calculating the prime after the user has given a number.

Comment: When I get confused on which brace is closing the other, I start from the top, just clicking the open-braces, and seeing where the IDE (e.g. Eclipse, Netbeans, InteliJ) will highlight the matching brace which is closing the one I clicked. Also, @flakes is right, indentation is the right way to go, it will make your reading much easier.

Comment: @Zerenity if any of the answers solved your problem, please accept it as the solution. And when you get enough points to be allowed to up-vote, remember to up-vote the ones which were useful as well.

Comment: got it, finally got it sorted out :D

Answer (score 0):

I went through your program and fixed it, including the prime number loop. I made three changes:

1. I moved the end of the do-while loop so that it doesn't repeat things.
2. I fixed the prime number loop. To do this I added a boolean "isPrime" which is set to false whenever a number is found to be non-prime.
3. I changed the ending condition to entering a value of 0 or less. I did this because when I tested it, I kept accidentally entering my next number where it asked me if I wanted to continue.

   import java.util.Scanner;

   class PrimeNumber{
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

   ```
       int value = 0;
       boolean isPrime = true;     // This needs to be set to true before the for loop

       do{
           System.out.println("Enter integer ");            
           value = console.nextInt();

           // End the program if a value is less than or equal to zero
           if (value <= 0) {
               System.out.println("bye bye");
               break;
           }

           isPrime = true;
           for(int i = 2; i < value; i++){

               if(value % i == 0){ // checks if value is evenly divisible by any number
                   System.out.println(value + " is not a prime number ");

                   // No sense in continuing this if it's not prime
                   isPrime = false;
                   break;
               }
           }

           // If the loop goes all the way through, then value is prime
           if (isPrime) {
               System.out.println(value + " is a prime number ");
           }

           System.out.println("value = " + value);
       } while (value > 0);

       console.close();
   }
   ```

   }

One thing that may help you is to get an IDE such as BlueJ. One thing that it does well is to show you the blocks of code.

Comment: Thanks, but now my "would you like to continue" thingy is gone which was part of my exercise question :C is BlueJ like an extension, or is it an editor. right now im using jgrasp. is bluej a better choice?